# DISTINCT COUNT Correlated subquery SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

It was trying to solve the below question

> Write a query to find the salesmen who have multiple customers.

Database:

```
customer_id  cust_name     city        grade       salesman_id
-----------  ------------  ----------  ----------  -----------
3002         Nick Rimando  New York    100         5001
3005         Graham Zusi   California  200         5002
3001         Brad Guzan    London      100         5005
3004         Fabian Johns  Paris       300         5006
3007         Brad Davis    New York    200         5001
3009         Geoff Camero  Berlin      100         5003
3008         Julian Green  London      300         5002
3003         Jozy Altidor  Moncow      200         5007
```

To which my solution was:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customer o
WHERE 2 <= (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id)
            Customer i
            WHERE o.salesman_id = i.salesman_id)
```

I am not getting why is it wrong. I am trying it [here](https://www.w3resource.com/sql-exercises/subqueries/sql-subqueries-inventory-exercise-16.php). But when I try to execute it I get no result

Expected Result:

```
salesman_id     city    
5001            New York
5002            Paris
```

Comment: What's your expect result?

Comment: @D-Shih Added the expected result

Comment: How can you get `commission` from you expect result?

Comment: @D-Shih Removed the columns referencing to another table. My bad. If you go over the link which I am referring to you may see the output which I mentioned earlier

Comment: OK I see I wrote an answer wish help you

Answer (score 1):

You should `group by salesman_id` and check `count(*)` to be `>= 2`:

```
SELECT salesman_id, count(*) as counter 
FROM Customer 
group by salesman_id
having count(*) >= 2;
```

and if you want the salesmen details:

```
select salesman.salesman_id, salesman.city from salesman
inner join (
    SELECT salesman_id, count(*) as counter 
    FROM customer 
    group by salesman_id
    having count(*) >= 2
) as t
on t.salesman_id = salesman.salesman_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but can you tell why my query is wrong

Comment: You are geting rows from Customer though you should get rows from salesman

Comment: First you must get the salesam_ids that have at least 2 customers from the table customer by the subquery and then join it to the salesman table to get the details of each salesman.

Comment: But if you see my expected result there I want `salesman_id` and `city`  which are both in `Customer` table

Comment: You want the name and the city of the salesman which are in the salesman table

Comment: The column city in customer is the customer's city. Could be the same or not with the city of the salesman

Comment: Just one last thing :). Ignoring the expected output can you explain what my query is doing

Comment: You would get 4 rows, one for each customer that has a salesman with more than 1 customer

Answer (score 1):

I saw your link you might try to use JOIN with aggregate function in a subquery.

get count greater than one by `salesman_id`.

```
SELECT s.salesman_id,s.city
FROM 
(  select salesman_id
    FROM  Customer i
    GROUP BY i.salesman_id
    having count(*) > 1
)o JOIN Salesman s on s.salesman_id = o.salesman_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but can you tell why my query is wrong

Comment: Because you only select `Customer` table but your expect result need to get data from `Salesman` so you need to use `join`

Comment: Even if I just want the columns from customer table as mentioned in my updated Expected Result where I just want salesman_id and city, I am not getting any output

Answer (score 1):

Just use a `JOIN` with `HAVING count(*)>1`

```
SELECT s.salesman_id, s.city
  FROM salesman s
  JOIN customer c on c.salesman_id = s.salesman_id
 GROUP BY s.salesman_id, s.city
 HAVING count(*)>1;

 salesman_id     city    
 5001            New York
 5002            Paris
```

*With respect to your logic, you can consider the following (by taking `2<=` into the inner query by using `exists` keyword ) and share also `salesman` table that's used in the referenced link:*

```
SELECT o.salesman_id, o.city
  FROM salesman o
 WHERE EXISTS
       (
        SELECT i.salesman_id
          FROM Customer i
         WHERE o.salesman_id = i.salesman_id
         GROUP BY i.salesman_id
        HAVING 2 <= count(distinct i.customer_id) 
       );

 salesman_id     city    
 5001            New York
 5002            Paris
```

Answer (score 1):

If the salesperson/customer rows are unique, then:

```
select salesman_id, count(*) as counter 
from Customer 
group by salesman_id
having count(*) >= 2;
```

If there are duplicates, then:

```
select salesman_id, count(*) as counter 
from Customer 
group by salesman_id
having count(distinct customer_id) >= 2;
```

However, if you want the original details, I would use `exists`:

```
select c.*
from customer c
where exists (select 1
              from customer c2
              where c2.salesman_id = c.salesman_id and
                    c2.customer_id <> c.customer_id
             );
```

Your query is wrong because the subquery is missing a `FROM` clause.  So, it has a syntax error.

It has two other issues, neither of which is fatal.  The reference to `customer_id` in the subquery should be qualified (i.e. `i.customer_id`).  Finding problems caused by unqualified columns is correlated subqueries can be really painful, so just qualify all columns.

The second issue is that `COUNT()` is overkill from a performance perspective.  Basically all the matching rows need to be processed to calculate the `count()` for the comparison.  `EXISTS` is a much better choice for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Your expected result makes little sense with only the customer table shown. You say you want to find the salesmen who have more than one customer. The only city you are showing us is in the customer table and we can see that a salesman's customers can reside in different cities. So which city to show for a salesman then?

Your demo link shows an additional salesmen table and there we can see that a salesman record, too, has a city. This must be the one you want to show. You should have shown the salesmen table in your request.

Here is how to find the salesmen. There is no need for a `distinct` count, as a customer should only occur once in a customer table of course.

```
select *
from salesman
where salesman_id in
(
  select salesman_id
  from customer 
  group by salesman_id
  having count(*) > 1
);
```

As to your own query (where you are trying to show all customer rows for the salesmen who have more than one customer - which is not quite what is being asked) see Gordon Linoff's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe due to scoping?

Have you tried changing `COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id)` to `COUNT(DISTINCT i.customer_id)`? Because that is the customer_id you want to have counted, not `o.customer_id`.